# How to get ngModel from a custom component?

Tags: angular, components, ngmodel

I have a form with a custom component

```html
<app-custom-component [(ngModel)]="myValue"></app-custom-component>
```

In the custom component i have an input which i also use `ngModel`

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="myValue" />
```

Basically `myValue` is bound to a custom model and the same `myValue` is bound to the input inside the custom model. I want the errors of the input's `ngModel` to bubble up to the form where the custom model is. So, in the form, I would have a save button that will be disabled if `app-custom-component` model is invalid.

is this even possible? if so how?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `myValue` name for both variables? If not, please try to update the question with different names. At the moment, it's difficult to follow which `myValue` you mean.

Comment: You need to implement custom `ControlValueAccessor` in order to bind ngModel with component .

Answer (score 0):

Reactive forms would solve this.
You can bind the same `FormControl` to both components. `FormControl` contains the validation errors and the state in itself.

```js
constructor(public FB: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
   myControl = this.fb.control(myValue, /*validators and other configuration */);
}
```

```html
<app-custom-component [formControl]="myControl"></app-custom-component>
<input [formControl]="myControl" />
```